# Google cloud free credits

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hi I am new to the Google cloud platform. I am currently using Google cloud free trail. I am planning to upgrade my billing account, but I have tons of credit left. What happens to my remaining credit after I upgrade to a paid subscription? Will these credits expire after the end of 3 months trial period even if I upgrade my subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All unused credits will expire after the end of the free trial period.
No matter if you upgrade to a paid account or you just keep using always-free services.

[Upgrading to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade)

> If you upgrade before the trial is over: Any remaining, unexpired Free
> Trial credits remain in your Cloud Billing account. You can continue
> to use the resources you created during the Free Trial without
> interruption.